# Key error when grouping by a column in Python

Tags: python, keyerror

I have a dataframe with temperature data for years 2012 and 2013. I would like to calculate the average temperature for both years.

I use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

year_avg = df['temperature'].groupby('year').mean().sort_values(by='year').reset_index()
```

Python throws an error: KeyError: 'year'

These are the data types for columns temperature and year

temperature                    1904 non-null   float64
year                           1904 non-null   int64

Could you give any hints why the error is being thrown?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You are doing

```
year_avg = df['temperature'].groupby('year').mean().sort_values(by='year').reset_index()
```

which mean *take `temperature` column from df and group by `year`* which is impossible as there is not `year` now, only `temperature`. You should retrieve `temperature` after processing not before i.e.

```
year_avg = df.groupby('year').mean().sort_values(by='year').reset_index()['temperature']
```

Comment: You are right. Actually I am using 

year_avg = df[['temperature']].groupby('year').mean().sort_values(by='year').reset_index()

An equivalent code (just with different column names) worked for a different dataframe.

Comment: Thank you both. Your code worked. I appreciate your contribution and I also finally figured out whtat the problem with my original code was. In the dataframe, there were another columns that needed to be added into the groupby clause. Ah I could have figured it out sooner.

Answer (score 3):

With `df['temperature']` you are returning a DataFrame with only one column `temperature`, therefore it does not have `year` anymore

```
df[['year','temperature']].groupby('year').mean().sort_values(by='year').reset_index()
```